# How to get data from parent table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, sequelize.js

**I am using  Sequelize dependency**

I want to get data from the parent table, I have a table **tblroute** which is associated with **routedetails** .**tblroute**'s **id** is the foreign key in **routedetails**

```
router.get('/bookingdetails', passengerMiddleware, (req, res) => {
tblBookingdetail.sync().then(() => {
    tblBookingdetail.findAll({
        where: {
            passengerId: req.passenger.id
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: tblRoute,
                as: 'route',
                include: [
                    {
                        model: tblRouteDetails,
                        as: 'routedetails'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }).then(data => {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            return res.json(baseResponse.sendSuccess('data', data));
        } else {
            return res.json(baseResponse.sendError('data not found'));
        }
    });

})
```

})

it gives following error
**Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: tblRouteDetail is not associated to tblRoute!**

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to fetch result set without having a relationship define inside model `tblRouteDetail`.

Open your model `tblRouteDetail` and add a relationship between both table like below.

```
 tblRoute.associate = function associate({ tblRouteDetail }) {
    return tblRoute.hasOne(tblRouteDetail, {
      foreignKey : 'tblroute_id'
    });
  };
```

It might help you to understand.

Comment: both tables are in the relationship
see this:

tblRouteDetail.belongsTo(tblRoute, { as: 'route' })

Comment: Have you defined a relationship on `tblRoute` model?

Comment: No bcoz tblroutedetails belongs to tblroute, I want to fetch data from tblroute to tblroutedetails .? Can Possible. But when I am trying to fetch data from tblroutedetails to tblroute it gives the result

Comment: @X3Vikas as per your script (above) you are fetching `tblRouteDetails` result through `tblRoute` model. Thats why you need to define relation on `tblRoute` model.

Comment: `tblRouteDetails` know the relation with `tblRoute` but `tblRoute` model doesn't know about relation with `tblRouteDetails`.

Comment: when I create a relationship from tblroutedetails to tblroute then we can access data from both tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190091/discussion-between-x3vikas-and-narayan-sharma).